# In MongoDB how is text stemmed if my text contains a UUID?

Tags: mongodb, uuid, stemming

I'm investigation slow updates on a collection in MongoDB.
The former colleagues have chosen the string type for the `_id` field and basing indexes on other string fields.

Now I understand text indexes are stemmed, and I can imagine this can be quite heavy when a document is updated.
Also the content of the `_id`-field is a UUID. Now I don't fully understand how stemming works, but guessing each part of the UUID (`part1-part2-part3-part4-etc`) becomes a unique entry in the index, causing queries to be slow.

Can someone explain how stemming would work on text which contains a UUID?

Comment: Investigation of performance questions is more on-topic for [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb), but you'd need to provide more context such as: log lines and metrics for slow updates, your specific version of MongoDB server, and your deployment type (standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster). If your concern is updates on a specific collection, the size & number of indexes for that collection would be useful context.  Performance questions can be challenging to investigate (often they are tip of the iceberg), so more specific details will help with an outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stemming only applies to string fields that are part of a [`text` index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/). The options for the default `_id` index cannot be changed and an `_id` index cannot be a `text` index, so stemming is not applicable in this context. The `_id` value is a single entry in the index which must be unique.

> Now I don't fully understand how stemming works, but guessing each part of the UUID (`part1-part2-part3-part4-etc`) becomes a unique entry in the index, causing queries to be slow.

[Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) uses language-specific heuristics to reduce words to their expected root forms. Stemming libraries have a notion of typical inflection rules for languages but do not have any understanding of valid words or grammar. It generally doesn't make sense to include a UUID field (or other random non-language string) in a `text` index definition.

MongoDB `text` indexes use the open source [Snowball library](https://snowballstem.org/) for stemming.

> Can someone explain how stemming would work on text which contains a UUID?

The best approach would be to [explain MongoDB `$text` queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to see exactly how they are parsed. However, there's also an [online Snowball demo](https://snowballstem.org/demo.html) which can be useful if you want to quickly try stemming algorithms for different languages.

A MongoDB `text` index or `$text` query will treat whitespace and most punctuation characters (including hyphens) as word delimiters, so `part1-part2-part3-part4-etc` would be split into 5 *terms*. Each term will be stemmed and any duplicate terms will be ignored. Terms made up of random letters or values like `part1` won't have a root form outside of accidental matching by the stemming heuristics.

For example, in English:

- Words ending in a single `s` are generally plural. If you make up a random word like `part4s` , it will stem to `part4`.
- Words ending in `ss` are generally not plural, so `part4ss` will be left unchanged.

You can see how a phrase would be stemmed by explaining a text search query and looking at the terms for the `parsedTextQuery`.

Using the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.stores.createIndex( { name: "text", description: "text" } )
> db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "part1-part2-part3-part4-etc-part4s-part4ss" } } ).
       explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan.parsedTextQuery
{
    "terms" : [
        "etc",
        "part1",
        "part2",
        "part3",
        "part4",
        "part4ss"
    ],
    "negatedTerms" : [ ],
    "phrases" : [ ],
    "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
}
```

I added `part4s` and `part4ss` to your example UUID. Since `part4s` stems to `part4` (which is already a unique term) you'll notice my query only finds 6 terms instead of 7.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Great help :-)